# Multi-monitor setup, new app always opens up in primary - possible to change?

Tags: debian, xrandr, multi-monitor

- Bunsenlabs Beryllium (Debian Bullseye)
- Openbox
- jgmenu

I've connected 2 external screens to my laptop. Physical layout:

[image]

- DP-4 laptop screen
- HDMI-0 external HDMI
- DP-0 external DisplayPort

`xrandr` script:

```
xrandr --output DP-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 3840x0 --rotate right --output DP-1 --off --output DP-2 --off --output DP-3 --off --output HDMI-0 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x420 --rotate normal --output DP-4 --primary --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x840 --rotate normal
```

Bunsenlabs doesn't have a desktop, just Openbox. Applications are opened from `jgmenu`, which opens with right-click. Another way to open the menu is <kbd>Win</kbd> key. `jgmenu` always opens in the screen where the cursor is.

A new application always opens in the primary screen, marked with the black stripe. This can sometimes be inconvenient, for example primary screen showing a fullscreen video while I'm working on a lab setup on another screen.

Changing primary works in the sense that the new application opens in a different screen, but still the primary screen. I'd like to get the new application opening in the screen where my cursor is, but haven't found a way to force it. Is there one?

Comment: Doesn't changing the primary work ?

Comment: Sure does, but doesn't resolve the issue as such - the application still opens in primary screen, not the one I want it to open in :-)